# In episode 55 of Dragon Ball Super, what does Goku's action to the King of All towards the end mean?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In episode 55 of *Dragon Ball Super*, when Goku meets with the King of All towards the end, Goku lifted him up and down and he said, "No one else can do it."

Does this mean Goku was special or just that the King of All would usually just wipe them out of existence?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at here. Are you asking *why* he says "No one else can do it"?

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking". OP, if you can come back and clarify what your question is, I will gladly retract my close vote.

Comment: Edited it to make it more clear, but I don't get the last part, "just that the King of All would usually just wipe them out of existence?" So, OP, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just due to the fact that everyone else fears the King of All because he can wipe out the universes that people are too afraid to approach him casually.

In this regard, Goku is the only one who can do it because Goku's personality makes him extremely bold and un-phased when dealing with beings which could wipe him or anyone else out of existence.